# Не работает JS. Всего 2 строки. Помогите разобраться что не так

Tags: javascript

Добавляю в свой js вот такие две строки:

var crimeblock = document.getElementsByClassName("crim-block");
crimeblock.classList.add("test");

После этого всё что идет после второй строки не работает. Если вторую строку закомментировать то снова всё в работе. Хоть убей не понимаю почему не работает добавление класса и почему вообще дальше код ломается? помогите плиз.

Comment: Потому что метод в первой строке возвращает коллекцию. Чтобы каждому её элементу присвоить класс их надо перебирать циклом.

Comment: Хоть дубликат чуть-чуть о другом, но суть та же

Comment: я пробовал тоже самое сделать по getelementbyid. Было также. Можешь подсказать как сделать лучше. Цель у меня такая: по клику на один элемент (ссылку) у другого должно поменяться свойство display с none на block. Вообщем у меня есть ссылка на одной странице и раскрывающийся знаком + список на другом. Мне необходимо, чтобы при переходе по ссылке страница открылась уже с раскрытым списком. Будет вообще в данном случае работать просто добавление класса?